# Any equivalent of Rust's Arc::try_unwrap in c++?

Tags: c++, rust

This is a c++ ecosystem question - though it is easiest to ask to refer to Rust.

Are there stable implementations of a thread-safe / reference count smart pointers which support to "unwrap" it in a thread-safe manner - under the condition that there is ref-count of exactly 1, as in  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap.

Coarsely, speaking std::shared_ptr is similar to ARC, but this use-case seems not to be supported, nor does it appear straight forward to implement (e.g. see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count#Notes).

Comment: What are you trying to implement that requires this functionality?

Comment: If this is only for debugging purposes, maybe you want [TSAN](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual)?

Comment: Could you please describe, what unwrap does or should do? The description talks about an inner value. Do you want to get a plain pointer out of a shared_ptr and destroying the shared_ptr without destroying the underlying object or do you want to get the reference count or a value copy of the pointed-to object? Perhaps you could also add an example use-case.

Comment: I don't think something like that exists, no. If `use_count` would work, you could then move out the value. But it doesn't seem to be reliable, from what I read from the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The exhaustive API of `std::shared_ptr` is available online (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) and as you can see there is no built-in support.

Furthermore, due to race-conditions with the promotion of `std::weak_ptr`, it is not possible to safely use `use_count` or `unique` to implement such functionality -- and `unique` was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20.

As a result, the functionality is simply not available with `std::shared_ptr`.

There may be other implementations of `std::shared_ptr` which offer this functionality -- though Boost's doesn't appear to.

---

As noted in the notes of `use_count`, the primary difficulty in implementing this function is the potential race-condition with `weak_ptr` promotion. That is, a naive:

```
//  Susceptible to race-conditions, do not use!
if (pointer.use_count() == 1) {
    return std::move(*pointer);
}
return std::nullopt;
```

Would not work because between the check and the actual move, a new shared owner may have appeared in another thread allowing concurrent access to the value.

The only ways to have this functionality safely are:

1. The `shared_ptr` implementation does not support weak pointers in the first place.
2. The `shared_ptr` implementation provides it, and ensures the absence of race condition with `weak_ptr` promotion.

I note that the latter typically requires locking the same lock used for `weak_ptr` promotion; hence why it cannot be provided externally.

A weaker variant could be implemented if `unique` were also guaranteeing the absence of `weak_ptr`. Although it would not be strictly equivalent as the presence of any `weak_ptr` would cause it to fail, it could still be useful in many scenarios where no `weak_ptr` is created.